# HeapDump and ThreadDump to specified folder java

Tags: java, jvm, profiling

I am trying to store Heapdump/Threaddump to specific folder(/home/amit/tmp) on linux, I have tried different JVM option, but not successful.

I have tried following option:

```
    -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/amit/tmp
```

and

```
    -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/amit/tmp
```

both are not working. 
Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: Don't you get a dump at all or is it in the wrong directory? Are you sure that an OutOfMemoryError occurs?

Comment: How do you get thread dump?

Comment: I have designed the program in that way to produced OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: Did you run your program and visually confirm that it threw an OutOfMemoryError?